# MYSQL Update data based on top 10 records of each user

Tags: mysql, innodb, join, subquery

I have a table `users` and other table `user_scores`. In `user_scores`, I save daily score of every user based on a algorithm. Now I want to calculate AVG `user_score` by only considering latest 10 records of `user_score` in `user_scores` table. I have tried following two queries but not successful with these.

1.

```
UPDATE      user
SET         user.user_score = (
    SELECT AVG(score) as avg_score FROM (
        SELECT score FROM user_scores WHERE user_id = user.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10)as x)
```

I am facing error `Unknown column 'user.id' in 'where clause'` cuz I am not able to pass variable to subquery of the query

2. Other thing I have tried by JOIN but in JOIN I am not able to calculate AVG(score) of each user based on latest 10 records.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think there is a rule that prohibits passing a column through more than one level of subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE user
SET user_score = (
    SELECT AVG(score) 
    FROM (
        SELECT score 
        FROM user_scores 
        WHERE user_id = user.id 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 10
    ) AS latest_scores
);
```

This query first selects the latest 10 scores for each user from the `user_scores` table using a subquery. It then calculates the average of these scores and updates the `user_score` column in the user table for each respective user.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution, but first please see if this computes the avg_scores correctly:

```
SELECT
        user_id, AVG(score) AS avg_score
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := 0, @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(user_id != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := user_id,
                user_id, score, id
            FROM  user_scores
            ORDER BY
                user_id  DESC,
                id  DESC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 10
    GROUP BY user_id;
```

Recommend `INDEX(user_id, id, score)` on `user_scores` .

If that works, then a multi-table `UPDATE` may finish the task:

```
UPDATE   user
    JOIN ( the above ) AS y  USING(user_id)
    SET  user.user_score = y.avg_score;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created one function to handle this part, this way I could pass value into function and get user_score from function